# Is there a way to standardize latitude and longitude to be used as predictors in KNN algorithm?

Tags: k-nn

The predictors are latitude and longitude, and target variable is region.

Comment: Take the cosine of the longitude, and take the sine of the latitude. This way, points on either side of the anti-meridian (longitude 180) will be near each other in the transformed space. You may need to convert the longitude/latitude to radians first depending on the implementation of sin and cos that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modifying your data, use great circle distance for those features' conmponent of the cost function.